# Extract type string with Clang bindings

Tags: python, clang, llvm-clang

I am writing a python script(using python clang bindings) that parses C headers and extracts info about functions: name, return types, argument types.

I have no problem with extracting function name, but I can't find a way to convert a `clang.cindex.Type` to C type string. (e.g. `clang.cindex.TypeKind.UINT` to `unsigned int`)

Currently, as a temporary solution, i have a dictionary `clang.cindex.TypeKind -> C type string` and code to process pointers and const qualifiers, but I didn't found a way to extract structure names.

Is there a generic way to get C definition of `clang.cindex.Type`? If there isn't, how can I get C type string for `clang.cindex.TypeKind.RECORD` and `clang.cindex.TypeKind.FUNCTIONPROTO` types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `RECORD`, the function `get_declaration()` points to the declaration of the type (a `union`, `enum`, `struct`, or `typedef`); getting the spelling of the node returns its name. (Obviously, take care between differentiating the `TYPEDEF_DECL` vs. the underlying declaration kind.)

For `FUNCTIONPROTO`, you have to use a combination of `get_result()` and `get_arguments()`.